# If the size of my home directory is 9GB and I want to increase it, should I increase size of my home partition or root partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

The size of my home directory is small, and I want to increase it using gparted.

Comment: If you are afraid of doing this I would suggest a 3rd option:  move your personal data to that partition you want to add. Keep /home empty from personal data and you have an easier life when you need to reinstall and when needing to to backups. See `~./config/users_dirs.dirs`  on how to do this,

Comment: Please update your question by opening the terminal and including the output from `df -h`

Comment: @N0rbert I don't like that this question currently has 4 close votes for being unclear, all 4 of which were cast after the answer to this question was accepted. When it comes to unclear questions at Ask Ubuntu I've seen much worse than this one, i.e. totally incoherent questions. The OP could step up his game by editing this question, but there's probably no longer any motivation for him to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On which partition is your home directory located, on home partition or on root partition?

- If you have a separate home directory, increase the size of your home partition.
- If you *don't* have a separate home directory, increase the size of your root partition to create more space for your home directory.
- *Optionally* GParted can also create a separate home partition if a home partition does not already exist.

New installations of Ubuntu 18.04 create one partition for everything by default, and a swap file will be created instead of a swap partition. This allows for maximum flexibility in making use of the disk space that is allocated to Ubuntu.